# Using pyaudio to convert volume to string

Tags: python, macos, audio

Is there a way to get the volume from a live microphone input and print it every half second or so? I found [this post](http://hlung.in.th/post/778936901/measure-real-time-microphone-input-volume-in-python), and I took out the OpenCV parts, because I can't get that to install, but when I run it, it just plays a really freaky echo thing on my computer that I can speak into. Its pretty fun, but not what I am looking for. Is there any other way. I would prefer to use PyAudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python [`audioop`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/audioop.html) module to do this:

```
chunk = stream.read(chunk_size)  # here stream is your PyAudio Stream
mx = audioop.max(chunk, 2)       # 2 is the width, here corresponding to paInt16
```

Here `mx` will be the maximum amplitude within the chunk, which is basically the linear volume (one could also use log of this for dB like volume).

(Of course to do this you need to get PyAudio working, and I know from your other question that it's not, but once it is, this should work, at least I use it all the time.)

Comment: Would I then `print(mx)`? EDIT: I guess so. This answer worked perfectly for me!